# Array with char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, char, fgets

I want to create an array with `malloc` and then assign the fields of the array an output of `fgets`.

```
char *words;
words = (char *)malloc(lines*sizeof(char));
int k = 0;
words[k] = (char *)malloc(mysize*sizeof(char));
```

This won't work because of the missing pointer I guess. What can I do?

Comment: You must allocate words as an array of pointers to chars instead of array of chars .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I want to create an array with malloc and then assign the fields of the array an output of fgets. ?* Then hopefully you should declare `words` as double pointer or array of char pointer.

One way is, by using **array of char pointer** like below.

```
char *words[lines]; /* array of pointer, lines is nothing but number of line in file */
for(int row = 0;row < lines; row++) {
    /* allocate memory for each line */
    words[row] = malloc(mysize);/* mysize is nothing but lines has max no of char i.e max no of char */
    /* now read from file */
    fgets(word[row],mysize,fp);/* reading from file(fp) & store into word[0],word[1] etc */
}
```

Or you can use double pointer like `char **words;` also.

And once job is done, at last don't forget to free the dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: And type casting the result of `malloc()` is not required as you did like `words = (char *)malloc(lines*sizeof(char));`. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Because it is already a char pointer, right? Just coded it in the form we've learned in our lecture.

Comment: Read the link i added. Its very useful.